# Azure Kubernetes auto-scaling: how to get it to automatically create a new node?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

Using the Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) preview, I have created an autoscaling cluster using a command like:

**az aks create  --resource-group MRRKub3  --name MRRKub3 --node-count 1  --enable-addons monitoring --kubernetes-version 1.14.1 --generate-ssh-keys --windows-admin-password xxx  --windows-admin-username xxx  --enable-vmss  --network-plugin azure --enable-cluster-autoscaler --min-count 1  --max-count 3**

I've deployed a toy Windows application that consumes a lot of CPU in a tight loop, and I can see in Insights on the Azure web portal that the single node is indeed using 99% CPU.
However, I can't get the autoscaling to kick in: no additional nodes are being created.

What parameters do I need to set (and where) to get Azure Kubernetes to realize that I want it to autoscale based on CPU use?

I'm interested in the new cluster autoscaling, not so much in the older horizontal autoscaling.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the autoscaling rules direclty in the VMSS (manually) - those should be managed by the k8s cluster autoscaler only.

You should use the cli commands to configure autoscale rules of the k8s autoscaler like:

```
kubectl autoscale deployment azure-vote-front --cpu-percent=50 --min=3 --max=10
```

as in this tutorial:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-scale